# guiminer shares 0 accepted 6 stale/invalid,what does the message mean?

Tags: mining-pools, terminology, guiminer

I am using guiminer .The pool is deepbit.com.
when I start mining, states show `shares 0 accepted 6 stale/invalid`
What does the message mean?

Comment: This is a very similar question to this one: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/what-are-stale-shares-and-what-can-i-do-to-avoid-them You may be processing or transmitting too slowly for your work to be accepted.

Comment: Welcome to the site! And yes, the question has been asked before - the search bar is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Uh Oh, the high level answer is it means you are not getting any bitcoins.

The lower level answer is harder to figure out without more information, basically, somewhere in the software/hardware stack is a problem that is preventing you from returning valid shares.  It could be a hardware problem but most likely it is just a configuration problem.

In the comments below, can you answer:
1:  What hardware are you running this on?  CPU?  GPU? model?
2:  What does your GUIminer window look like (attach a screen shot).
3:  Did you create a worker on deepbit.com?

Welcome to StackExchange!