# I am new to bitcoin, and GUI miner won't work on slush's server

Tags: mining-pools, gpu-mining, guiminer

I am new to using bitcoin, and I don't have any mining hardware, just my computer. I got GUIminer, and set the server to other, and the host name to http://api.bitcoin.cz, port 8332. I entered my username and worker name, and it's now mining (very slowly, as expected) but still mining, however, it says on slush's server that i don't have any active workers and I'm not mining, anybody know what the problem is? I also have 1 stale share, what is that, and how did i get it?

Comment: Juleon5456, I just wanted to note that it's possible that you actually are mining and connected but you just aren't solving shares quickly enough to even register with the pool that you are mining. The fact that you had a stale share makes me inclined to think that this is in fact what is happening. For more info on stale shares, [go here](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/what-are-stale-shares-and-what-can-i-do-to-avoid-them).

Comment: I disagree that it is a duplicate; the question acknowledges the fact that mining will be slow. StephenM347's comment about would be a good answer, I think.

Comment: @PieterWuille You're right, I should have removed the "duplicate comment" when I wrote my own answer. :) My answer was actually there when Stephen commented.

Answer (score 2):

Your hashpower is magnitudes too low. It is so low, that the pool doesn't accept your work, because it will never amount to any use. You are competing with a teaspoon in a world of [Bucket-wheel excavators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket-wheel_excavator). You will be expending energy and never gain any revenue. Please check out [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406) for a more comprehensive overview of the mining situation.

Shares are simpler portions of work at a lower difficulty than blocks. They are used by mining pools to gauge the contribution of miners. You apparently found a single share, but it was found after the pool had started working on a new block. When your `guiminer` told the pool about it, it was already outdated.

Answer (score 0):

It may be very low hash power, however, your miner should still show up. Current instructions from Slush Pool include using the Stratum address e.g.: `stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333` see this page: 
https://slushpool.com/help/get-started/getting_started

This is not an entirely new or unknown issue so it could have been the problem when the question was asked: 
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=216605.0

Answer (score -1):

Buenas noches amigos les hablas Carlos Mendoza desde Caracas Venezuela, espero se encuentren bien y obtengan mucho exito en el minado, me encuentro en esta pagina por los siguientes motivos.

Soy un programador y diseñador de websites, un placer.

Hace poco me meti en el minado de Bitcoin, estoy minando por varias paginas web, pero no es muy rentable al menos que inviertas.

Tambien me informe sobre GUIminer un sotware para minar Bitcoin con las GPU, pero tengo unos detalles me gustaria un poco de asesoria. Ok tengo el minero instalado pero no quiere leerme las GPU ¿Tengo que instalar otro programa?

Espero sus respuestas. Gracias.

Comment: gereralemente hablamos aqui ingles, quando tienes una pregunta pregunta, use el traductor de Google y póngalo aquí. Esto hace que sea más fácil encontrar una respuesta adecuada :-)

Comment: That is not a response to the question on this page.  If you have only a question, it's best to post it as its own question, rather than depicting it as an answer to someone else's question.